# Send document with preview using Telegram API

Tags: go, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm creating a bot which task is just to show the document with the preview. So firstly we send the document itself and the preview after that. I added screenshot of the desired result, but the actual result is just the doc itself. I don't understand why Thumb property is just ignored. By the way I tried `telebot` lib as well.

```
bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI(viper.GetString("tg_api_key"))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

u := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(0)
u.Timeout = 60

var docId tgbotapi.FileID

updates := bot.GetUpdatesChan(u)
for update := range updates {
    msg := update.Message
    if msg == nil {
        continue
    }

    var reply []string
    switch {
    case msg.Text == "/start":
        reply = []string{"Send me the document to be previewed"}
    case msg.Document != nil:
        docId = tgbotapi.FileID(msg.Document.FileID)
        reply = []string{"Now send me the thumbnail"}
    case msg.Photo != nil:
        doc := tgbotapi.NewDocument(msg.Chat.ID, docId)
        doc.Thumb = tgbotapi.FileID(msg.Photo[0].FileID)
        bot.Send(doc)
        continue
    default:
        reply = []string{"Unknown command"}
    }

    result := tgbotapi.NewMessage(msg.Chat.ID, strings.Join(reply, "\n"))
    bot.Send(result)
}
```

[image]